# Class typed as object with properties from the constructor... without casting custom constructor signature?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

```
class __Constants__ {
  [key: string]: string;
  constructor(values: string[]) {
    values.forEach((key) => {
      this[key] = key;
    });
  }
}

const Constants = __Constants__ as {
  new <T extends readonly string[]>(values: T): { [k in T[number]]: k };
};

const __colors__ = ["BLUE", "GREEN"] as const;

const Colors = new Constants(__colors__);
// const Colors: {
//   BLUE: "BLUE",
//   GREEN: "GREEN",
// }
```

Is it possible to type the `__Constants__` class so that it has the same return type as the cast but without using the custom constructor signature?

Edit: Note that I am working on converting a legacy JS codebase to Typescript and want to make as few JS code changes as possible. The real `Constants` class is more complicated, here I've isolated the current problem I was facing.

Comment: Why not use a string enum instead of this Constants class? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums

Comment: @LindaPaiste Yes if I were to write this code new I would not use a class like this (probably just a union of string literals would be fine), however I added a note to the question explaining that it is a JS -> TS conversion project and I want to make as few JS changes as possible. Thank you for your help!

Comment: In that case I'd say that you've done a good job with a difficult problem and I'm not sure that you can get any better.  It's always going to require some sort of assertion for typescript to understand which keys were set by `this[key]`.

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

```
const Constants = class {
  [key: string]: string;
  constructor(values: string[]) {
    values.forEach((key) => {
      this[key] = key;
    });
  }
} as {
  new <T extends readonly string[]>(values: T): { [k in T[number]]: k };
};


const __colors__ = ["BLUE", "GREEN"] as const;

const Colors = new Constants(__colors__);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwuaBDMUIwLw2AGyRdAbwCgYYBtAawFMBPALhmgCcBLMAcwF1GX2OA3KWyIozAK7AoIZgAoAbkhzjqEXmP7kuAShgkyZRctUA6AGYyAokmAALWbJq1dGAHx7hBmFFusIVOi5MGCchLwBfbTCYcOJwmHwPMjBqAHcYAB4AFRhqAA8oajAAE3RmaiRi8BxaJg1OLVcFJRU1GCztRkIKShh2dvIwcQBbACNqZi4eEJihcKFiYlBIWAB9VdAcGQh14PIAIgAhABkAVUt9gBoYfYBxACVLSwA5faDE5egFz9gELeZ0FgUukECsUGhZOtNtt1lFiAB6eEiFbwED-NokREGE7nRhHM4XS4IpFkB5PZ54skvK7EmLEIA)

It makes use of so called "Class expressions"

---

EDIT: I've tried out something else. Why don't you just use a function instead of a class? This works:

```
function Constants<T extends readonly string[]>(values: T): { [k in T[number]]: k } {
  const obj: any = {};
  values.forEach((key) => {
    obj[key] = key;
  });
  return obj;
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAYQQZygQzFNAeAFUQFMAPKYsAEzUQCdjMqEAbAT0QzpjAHMBtALoA+ABQA3TCxDE0ALkQEAlAoDeifgGtEPRfzAgAtgCNidQYIXaAvolUAoRIgjooiOMYBWC7BwC8dtYA3I6IktKyAHTAcHQAopgQABaioprEbEqIfsJ2oU4enloZgtmI6WwhTtZKVfTEUCB0SIUh1vYdLmAYiAD6vS4ssWj9ZfwARABCADIAqnHjADSI4wDiAEpxcQBy46WYtF0YIfZHbqhDdLQBqN1YOGii-YPD-bX2APQfzq4ocJfyPJfJyIGbzBRTOYLRafb5ODZbbYQhE7JawxDtIA)

Of course you have to call it like a function, not create a class instance:

```
const __colors__ = ["BLUE", "GREEN"] as const;

const Colors = Constants(__colors__); // don't use "new" here
```

Comment: Ah that is nicely more succinct! Thank you. However is it possible to avoid the `as` casting? It always leaves room to do it wrong or forget to be updated to the true representation of the original type.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not possible. I've tried it many different ways, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You can create a generic class, but getting typescript to understand which properties were set by this[key] is rough.  I haven’t played with this but I think that you do need some sort of assertion in order to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you for the help @blaumeise20 however I should have added that I am working on typing a legacy JS codebase and making as few as possible JS code changes, i.e. only adding types. I may consider refactoring this class to the function, but the real class is much more complicated making it riskier.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I've tried exactly that, but it gives me a lot more errors.